# Approach to Interplanetary Transfers in GMAT

Tags: orbital-mechanics, interplanetary, hohmann-transfer, gmat

I hope to find a straightforward process for designing interplanetary missions using the General Mission Analysis Tool (GMAT). This would involve calculating the required initial state, timing, and delta V for a manoeuvre to target the other planet. My desire is to use this in an educational setting.

I would like to use a Hohmann transfer calculated by the patched conic approximation as a starting point. This provides a date, turning angle, and delta V for the manoeuvre. What is the best way to iteratively solve for the delta V and the required initial Earth orbit in GMAT? What parameters should be varied?

My attempt at a mission sequence is shown below:

[image: Mission sequence]

Is there a better way to vary the initial orbital plane than Varying INC and RAAN as was done here? A large step change in RAAN can occur for small changes in near equatorial orbits, which can prevent convergence. Also, is there a Vary parameter that can be related to turning angle more straightforwardly than RAAN?

Edit: to be clear, this is a question about finding an orbital state and manoeuvre for interplanetary transfer. It is not about Hohmann transfers between Earth orbits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hohmann transfer using GMAT software](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/56073/hohmann-transfer-using-gmat-software)

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch of course it doesn't. When proposing duplicates it's necessary to do more than look for similar words in titles. That question author says " but I am unable to know how do I find relation between the velocity on impulsive burn (element-1) and the apogee of the second orbit." and that's what the answer there answers. Answers there don't work here, answers here don't work there, it's not helpful or productive to close this question and prevent answers in this case.